# Matching polynomial of complete graph

Tags: co.combinatorics

In my graduate discrete math course I talked about real-rootedness of some combinatorial polynomials, and as a homework asked for a proof of the real-rootedness of the matching polynomial (matching generating function) of the complete graph, 
$$
p_n(x) = \sum_{k \geq 0} m_{n,k} x^k
$$ 
where $m_{n,k}$ is the number of matchings of $K_n$ with $k$ edges. (These are essentially the Hermite polynomials.)

I was thinking of the recurrence 
$$
p_n(x) = p_{n-1}(x) + (n-1)xp_{n-2}x,
$$
with $p_0(x)=p_1(x)=1$, from which it is an easy induction that the roots of $p_n(x)$ and $p_{n-1}(x)$ are both all real, negative and distinct, that they interlace, and that the largest (least negative) root of $p_n(x)$ is closer to $0$ than the largest root of $p_n(x)$. (This is essentially Heilman and Lieb's proof that the matching generating function of any simple graph is real-rooted).

One of my students found instead the recurrence 
$$
p_n(x) = 1 + \binom{n}{2}\int_0^x p_{n-2}(t)~dt~~~~~(*)
$$ 
(or $p_n'(x)=\binom{n}{2}p_{n-2}(x)$), but neither he nor I were able to use this recurrence in an inductive proof that the roots of $p_n$ and $p_{n-2}$ are real, distinct, negative and interlace. (And this is not a fact I had previously known).

**Question**: Can the recurrence (*) be used to prove that the roots of $p_n(x)$ and $p_{n-2}(x)$ are real and interlace?

It's not generally true that if $a(x)$ is a polynomial with only real roots, and $b(x) = C_1 + C_2\int_0^x a(t)~dt$, then $b(x)$ has all real roots; take e.g. $C_1=C_2=1$ and $a(x)=1+2x+x^2$.

Comment: Since the recurrence alone does not suffice to prove the result, the question is what extra properties of the polynomials $p_n$ am I allowed to use? If you aren't careful in what you permit, you will end top with a proof that does not use the recurrence. Also, since the Hermite polynomials are an orthogonal family, there are a number of proof that their zeroes are real.

Comment: Good point, the question "can the recurrence be used to prove ..." may be somewhat imprecise. I know two proofs that $H_n(x)$ is real-rooted, one using (the analog of) the first recurrence above, the other using the definition of $H_n$ as $d^n/dx(e^{-x^2})$. Both show that the roots of $p_n(x)$ and $p_{n-1}(x)$ interlace; what is interesting to me is that I have only just noticed that the roots of $p_n(x)$ and $p_{n-2}(x)$ seem to interlace, can't proof it yet, and was wondering if it is known that recurrence (*) plus some clever trick is a route to getting this two-step interleaving.

Comment: Any orthogonal polynomial can be expressed as the characteristic polynomial of a symmetric tridiagonal matrix. This one of the simplest proofs that their zeros are real.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure about how to use this recurrence to show that the roots are real and distinct, but I think if we assume we know this via other methods, I can show that the roots of $p_n$ and $p_{n-2}$ are interlaced.

Indeed, let $r_1,\dots,r_k$ be the roots of $p_{n-2}$, and consider the intervals
$(\infty,r_1],(r_1,r_2],\dots,(r_k,\infty)$. Then $p_n$ is monotone on each of these intervals by $(\ast)$. Thus $p_n$ can have at most one root in each interval. Since we are assuming the roots of $p_n$ are real and distinct, and we know the degree of $p_n$ is one greater than the degree of $p_{n-2}$, we know that there is exactly one root in each interval by pigeonhole. Thus the roots are interlaced.